What is being proposed for converting UK NPPLs to PPLs?
There has been a lot of talk this year (both in person at flying clubs, online and in the monthly "Microlight" magazine published in the UK) about the CAA reviewing the license structure in the UK.
Currently there is no formal upgrade path from NPPL to PPL and only 10 hours can be credited towards training.
However, the CAA apparently are reviewing this, with a view to make changes in 2025. However, I have no idea what the proposed changes / path will be and can't seem to find that information online.
What are the proposed changes and what would a path from NPPL to PPL look like?
I recently enquired about adding an SSEA rating to my NPPL(m) license and was told there is no point due to the forthcoming changes.

For a little background, in 2023 the UK CAA launched a 3 phase consultation on General Aviation Pilot Licensing & Training Simplification. Much of this seems to have stemmed from the request to simplify licensing following Brexit, which has left us with a somewhat two-tiered licensing scheme.
There are in effect two Sub-ICAO licenses available

LAPL
NPPL

The responses to the first phase of the consultation, asking broadly what GA pilots would like the changes to be can be viewed here: https://www.caa.co.uk/publication/pid/11991
It is the proposals of the second Phase of the consultation which may go some way to answering this question. This can be read in full here (for aeroplanes and microlights): https://consultations.caa.co.uk/ga/pilot-licensing-review-phase-2-aeroplanes/
Section 4.24 & 4.25 of CAP274A lays out the **proposal **for PPL upgrade from the Sub-ICAO license

PPL upgrade
4.24  The proposed upgrade path from the sub-ICAO licence to the ICAO PPL(A) would consist of:

Meet the ICAO Annex 1 requirements;
Training as required at an ATO or DTO;
PPL skills test; and
Theoretical knowledge exams in:
▪ Air law and operational procedures;
▪ Aircraft General Knowledge – covering airframe, instruments, electrical systems, emergency equipment and powerplant;
▪ Principles of flight;
▪ Performance; and
▪ Radio navigation.

4.25 The ICAO Annex 1 requirements consist of:

40 hours flight time as a pilot of aeroplanes, appropriate to the class rating sought; and
10 hours of solo flight time appropriate to the class rating sought, under the supervision of an authorized flight instructor, including 5 hours of solo cross-country flight time with at least one cross-country flight totalling not less than 270 km (150 NM) in the course of which full-stop landings at two different aerodromes shall be made.


None of this is set in stone yet, and we have to wait for Phase 3 to complete which will be implementing the new rules.

Thanks Jamie! Can I ask, why the duplicate exams? Air law for example is part of the NPPL and if you already have a radio license, why re-do a radio nav exam?

I'm afraid I couldn't answer that. It's a question for the CAA if and when they change the rules.

Just 1 more question Jamie, if these changes are approved, when will they take effect? Just wondering if it's worth holding out on the SSEA rating and doing this instead if it'll be soon (in the next year or so)

Also, I thought you were a member of the CAA, apologies

I am by no means affiliated with the CAA.
